# Java calculator giving weird results

Tags: java, android

I'm having a problem with my Javacalculator. It sometimes gives me weird results, such as
357856 * 42342 = -2027530432

Could someone try to explain to me why this happens?
Also it crashes when I use too big numbers, but I think that's kind of normal.

Here's my activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#ABE033" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="@string/Zahl1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zahl1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zahl1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zahl1"
    android:text="@string/Zahl2"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/zahl2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Ergebnis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/zahl2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/zahl2"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:onClick="ButtonKlick"
    android:text="@string/Rechnen" />
```

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.rechner;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void ButtonKlick (View view) {
    int zahl1;
    int zahl2;
    int Ergebnis;
    EditText Feld1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl1);
    EditText Feld2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.zahl2);
    EditText FeldErgebnis = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Ergebnis);
    if (Feld1.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (Feld2.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    zahl1 = Integer.parseInt(Feld1.getText().toString());
    zahl2 = Integer.parseInt(Feld2.getText().toString());
    Ergebnis = zahl1 * zahl2;

    FeldErgebnis.setText(String.valueOf(Ergebnis));


}
}
```

Here's my strings.xml if you need it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string name="app_name">Rechner</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="Zahl1">Zahl 1:</string>
<string name="Zahl2">Zahl 2:</string>
<string name="Plus">:</string>

</resources>
```

Comment: Integer overflow?

Comment: That might be the cause. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the maximum size of int, I am pretty sure you passed it.

```
int Range : minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of (2^31)-1
long Range : minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of (2^63)-1
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Try using a long, or maybe some other data type.

Answer (score 2):

The max limit of `int` primitive type is **2,147,483,647** which is `lesser` than `(357856 * 42342) = 15152338752.` Hence it leads you to that weird answer. Use `long` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 1):

just overflow

```
groovy:000> 357856 * 42342
===> -2027530432
groovy:000> 357856 * 42342L
===> 15152338752
```

Answer (score 1):

The "int" data type has 32 bits, which allows for a max value of 2^31 - 1 = about 2 billion.
Your computation leads to a result of about 15 billion.
32 bit int will overflow, passing from 2 billion to -2 billion and hence your strange result.

For such large numbers use a 64 bits data type, like "long".

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of overflow. You are exceeding the range of the datatype int.

```
int Range : minimum value of -2^31 and a maximum value of (2^31)-1
Long Range : minimum value of -2^63 and a maximum value of (2^63)-1
```

Try switching to Long. Further read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)